# Complexity of existance a weighted cycle

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Assume weighted Graph G, vertices and edges are weighted, and given constant k, what is  the complexity of following decision problem A?

1-A: Dose G contane cycle with total weight K?
2- what is the complexity of A if G is a plannar graph?

Any idea or pointing to papers or book is also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It is NP-complete, since you can reduce from planar [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) with unit weights and k=n.